# Sum of products of Fibonacci numbers

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, fibonacci

Given a series

Fib(1) * Fib (n+2) + Fib(2) * Fib(n+1) + Fib(3) * Fib(n) + ......  + Fib(n-1) * Fib(4)

or Summation  **Fib(x) * Fib (n-x+3)** where x varies from 1 to n-1
where Fib(n) is nth number of Fibonacci series

to evaluate this series Fib(n) can be calculated using matrix exponentiation .

But the complexity for this is logn and for the n terms it would be nlogn .

**I want this series to get reduced to a single term or some other optimization to improve** **the time complexity .**

Any suggestions ??

Comment: Actually, you only need to calculate Fib(n + 2) and Fib(n + 1) with matrix multiplication, then find Fib(n) by subtracting. You notice that at roughly (n / 2 + 1), the series will repeat a previously seen element, so you don't need to calculate anymore.

Comment: But if you consider that the n-th Fibonacci number has Θ(n) digits/bits, it's quadratic. If `n` is so small that `Fib(n)` fits in a standard 64-bit integer, that doesn't matter, of course.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Nth term of the given series](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12252187/nth-term-of-the-given-series)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't reduce the sum to a single term, but it can be reduced to a sum of five terms, which reduces the complexity to `O(log n)` arithmetic operations.

However, `Fib(n)` has `Θ(n)` bits, so the number of bit-operations is not logarithmic. There is a multiplication of a number the size of `Fib(n)` with `n-1`, so the number of bit-operations is `M(n,log n)`, where `M(a,b)` is the bit-operation complexity of a multiplication of an `a`-bit number with a `b`-bit number. For the naive algorithm, `M(a,b) = a*b`, so the number of bit-operations in the below algorithm is `O(n*log n)`.

The fact that allows this reduction is that Fibonacci numbers (like all numbers in a sequence defined by a linear recurrence) can be written as the sum of pure exponential terms, in particular

```
Fib(n) = (α^n - β^n) / (α - β)
```

where

```
α = (1 + √5)/2;    β = (1 - √5)/2.
```

In addition to the Fibonacci numbers, I also use the Lucas numbers, which follow the same recurrence as the Fibonacci numbers,

```
Luc(n) = α^n + β^n
```

so the sequence of Lucas numbers (starting from index 0) begins with

```
2 1 3 4 7 11 18 29 47 ...
```

The relation `Luc(n) = Fib(n+1) + Fib(n-1)` allows an easy conversion between Fibonacci and Lucas numbers, and computation of `Luc(n)` in `O(log n)` steps can reuse the Fibonacci code.

So with the representation of Fibonacci numbers given above, we find

```
(α - β)^2 * Fib(k) * Fib(n+3-k) = (α^k - β^k) * (α^(n+3-k) - β^(n+3-k))
                                = α^(n+3) + β^(n+3) - (α^k * β^(n+3-k)) - (α^(n+3-k) * β^k)
                                = Luc(n+3) - ((-1)^k * α^(2k) * β^(n+3)) - ((-1)^k * α^(n+3) * β^(2k))
```

using the relation `α * β = -1`.

Now, since `α - β = √5` the summation `k = 1, ..., n-1` yields

```
   n-1                                              n-1                   n-1
5 * ∑ Fib(k)*Fib(n+3-k) = (n-1)*Luc(n+3) - β^(n+3) * ∑ (-α²)^k - α^(n+3) * ∑ (-β²)^k
   k=1                                              k=1                   k=1
```

The geometric sums can be written in closed form, and a bit of juggling yields the formula

```
n-1
 ∑ Fib(k)*Fib(n+3-k) = [5*(n-1)*Luc(n+3) + Luc(n+2) + 2*Luc(n+1) - 2*Luc(n-3) + Luc(n-4)]/25
k=1
```

Answer (score 2):

Steps to follow:

- Define `std::vector<int>` and fill it with all fibonacci numbers which you need. Compute these numbers using [dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming#Fibonacci_sequence); that is, make use of results which you already have computed. Don't compute the same value more than once!
- Once you have the vector filled with all the numbers you need, apply the formula `Fib(x) * Fib (n-x+3)` in a loop and compute the sum of the products.

Comment: This doesn't work too well for values of `n > 42` because these won't fit into `int`. However, I suspect that using an array of a suitable integer type is still more effective than computing `Fib(n)` each time, even if `Fib(n)` can be computed in O(n).

Comment: If somehow the given series can be reduced to a single term or sum few terms using some property of fibonacci terms like product of fibonacci terms etc .... it will do the job !!

Comment: The OP suggests a better (more efficient) solution to calculate the finobacci numbers (matrix exponentiation) this is `O(logn)` integer ops while you suggested an `O(n)` integer ops solution, I believe it is actually taking him backward rather then forward, especially given the fact that he specifically asked to improve *time complexity*.

Comment: @amit For the summation, you need all the Fibonacci numbers to `F(n)`, to get them all, the simple addition is the best you can do.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Yes, I did not think about getting *all* elements for some reason :|. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

assuming `f(n)=f(n-1)+f(n-2)` for `n>2` and `f(1)=f(2)=1`, `f(0)=0`

Let `E(n)=sum(k=1 .. n-1, f(k)f(n-k+3))` and `E'(n)=sum(k=0 .. n, f(k)f(n-k))` 
Clearly `E(n)=E'(n+3) - ( f(0)f(n+3) + f(n)f(3) + f(n+1)f(2) + f(n+2)f(1) + f(n+3)f(0) )`

On [wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FibonacciNumber.html) you'll find : `E'(n)= (nL(n)-f(n))/5`, with `L(n)=f(n+1)+f(n-1)`

from this : 
`5E(n)=(n+3)( f(n+4)+f(n+2) ) - 5(2f(n) + f(n+1) +f(n+2))`
`5E(n)=(n+3)( 4f(n+1)+3f(n) ) - 10f(n+1) -15f(n)`
`5E(n)= (4n+2)f(n+1) + (3n-6)f(n)`

Should be simple to evaluate, the complexity should be the same as the fibonnaci algorithm used,

Answer (score 1):

If I know what a [Lucas number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_number) is, then I can use the identity...

F(n)*F(m) = [L(m+n) - (-1)^n*L(m-n)]/5

See this reduces the sum of products of Fibonacci numbers into a sum of Lucas numbers.

Even better, since n+m is constant for each term, the sum reduces further. There are n-1 terms in this sum, so the sum reduces to a sum of Lucas numbers.

[(n-1)*L(n+3) + L(n+1) - L(n-1) + L(n-3) - ... + (-1)^(n-1)*L(5-n)]/5

As a test, for n = 5, I get 40, which is consistent with the direct sum of products:

1*13 + 1*8 + 2*5 + 3*3 = 40

For n = 1000, I get a sum of:

82283375600539014079871356568026158421560221654785733943009487102720
211767741849325389562067921531531130739623611293922046989610820831567088
516047002196966545744637588824274730947688693969572937880383134671205375

Even better, some extra work will let that sum of Lucas numbers contract further since the Lucas numbers of negative index have a simple relation to those with positive index.

As far as computing the k'th Lucas (as well as the k'th Fibonacci) number, it can be done quite efficiently as shown [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/34766-the-fibonacci-sequence).