# How to calculate a n-th element of this sequence in log(n) time or better?

Tags: c++, c, fibonacci, sequences

```
1 4 10 22 45 88 167
```

This sequence is the convolution of Fibonacci numbers with themselves.
The recurrence is

```
a[n] = a[n-1] + a[n-2] + Fibonacci[n+2]
```

If you assume Fibonacci sequence to start from `0,1,1,2,3,5 ...` (http://oeis.org/A213587)

How can I generate it is logarithmic time or faster?
Please note that this is no homework nor any contest problem. I am working on Fibonacci applied sequences.

Comment: Do you need the whole sequence? Because there isn't going to be a way to generate `O(n)` numbers in `O(log(n))`. If you just need the nth Number [look at wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Matrix_form) for a direct calculation formula.

Comment: Even copying from an already-done array is O(n)

Comment: I want to  calculate nth term of the sequence in nth time without using memorizing any values.

Comment: @Grizzly:Sir read my comments in response to the first answer for clarifications

Comment: @tuğrulbüyükışık:Sir read my comments in response to the first answer for clarifications

Comment: Okay, done. Here you go the new answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this in log n time by converting the recurrence relation to a fibonacci convolution..In the end ,the recurrence relation contained only Lucas Number and  Fibonacci Number.So I was able to solve it in 2*log n .I will write the whole proof here once I figure out how to write mathematical symbols here.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a closed formula and as such almost guaranteed to be `O(1)` (calculated using Mathematica)

**Input**:

```
RSolve[{a[n] == a[n - 2] + a[n - 1] + Fibonacci[n + 2], a[1] == 1, a[2] == 4}, a[n], n]
```

**Output** (click [here](http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?a_n%20=%20%5Cfrac%7B%5Cleft%28-2%20%5Cleft%281%2b%5Csqrt%7B5%7D%5Cright%29%5Cright%29%5E%7B-n%7D%20%5Cleft%284%5En%20%5Cleft%287142%2b3194%20%5Csqrt%7B5%7D-%5Cleft%281885%2b843%20%5Csqrt%7B5%7D%5Cright%29%20n%5Cright%29%2b%28-1%29%5En%20%5Cleft%281%2b%5Csqrt%7B5%7D%5Cright%29%5E%7B2%20n%7D%20%5Cleft%28-7142-3194%20%5Csqrt%7B5%7D%2b%5Cleft%2833825%2b15127%20%5Csqrt%7B5%7D%5Cright%29%20n%5Cright%29%5Cright%29%7D%7B5%20%5Cleft%287985%2b3571%20%5Csqrt%7B5%7D%5Cright%29%7D) for full size):

[image: link]

You will have to use some floating-point arithmetics but you can still get much precision from a double datatype. If precision is an issue, use GMP or some other arbitrary precision library.

Comment: ,I am bounded to use a pure programming language without any additional library.I code in c/c++/java/python ,so I ideally want a solution using features available in either of  these languages.

Comment: @thedarkknight: why would you need additional librarys to use that forumla? (though personally I would go with the one from wikipedia (linked in my comment on your question), due to it being more easily expressed).

Answer (score 1):

**This is not the actual answer to the question, just an approach to generate the whole sequence in `O(n)`**

Provided you mean `O(log(n))` time complexity to calculate just the n'th element, not all up to `n` it is actually quite easy. If you iterate through, you can easily do `O(1)` for each element with proper memoization.

I'll suppose this:

```
a[1] = 1, a[2] = 1, fib[1] = 0, fib[2] = 1, fib[3] = 1
```

Then just iterate and memorize `a[n-1]` and `a[n-2]` as well as `fib[n-1]` and `fib[n-2]` along the way:

```
long an_1 = 1;  // a[2]
long an_2 = 1;  // a[1]
long fib_1 = 2; // fib[4]
long fib_2 = 1; // fib[3]

// Starts with a[3]
while (true)
{
    long fib = fib_1 + fib_2;
    long an = an_1 + an_2 + fib;

    std::cout << an;

    fib_2 = fib_1;
    fib_1 = fib;
    an_2 = an_1;
    an_1 = an;
}
```

***Edit***: this is called [amortized complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortized_analysis). Computing up to the `n`-th element requires `O(n)` steps, but as you have all elements from `1` to `n` available when you reach this point the cost of computing each element is `O(1)`. The formal proof is a bit more elaborated but this is the idea.

Comment: Wouldn't that give you `O(n)` time?

Comment: I want to  calculate nth term of the sequence in nth time without using memorizing any values.

Comment: @Shahbaz As I clarified in the answer, that is `O(n)` for the whole sequence, `O(1)` for each individual term. Of course, you cannot calculate an individual term with this algorithm.

Comment: I want to calculate all values at run time no precomputation.

Comment: Please @Tibor if it is still unclear,I need an algorithm/hint to an algorithm that computes Nth term of the above sequence in logarithmic or faster time complexity for calculating that Nth term.

Comment: @Tibor: I am aware of the recurrence matrix method with modular exponentiation by squaring to calculate the N th fibonacci term in log n time.How should I modify this recurrence relation to do the same?

Comment: @thedarkknight I understand and I have edited your question to better reflect that. However, I do not know the actual answer, sorry.

Comment: @DanielFisher :sir where are you these days?

Comment: @Also what is use of this code if it is not valid for large N .It is obvious when I want the Nth term ,I want it accurately not something around that.

Comment: @thedarkknight you don't have the right attitude. Don't treat people who are trying to help you like this.

Comment: @thedarkknight I'm here. Late, but you misspelled my name ;) You may be interested in [this similar topic](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12250594/1011995). Analogous to the derivation there, you get the (simpler) formula `a(n) = (5*n*Luc(n+3) - 2*(Luc(n+1) + Luc(n-1)))/25`.

Comment: @UmNyobe:Sir I am  sorry for offending you and anyone else with my careless comments.However what I assumed was that perhaps since I posted the OEIS sequence ,it was likely that I wanted exact integer answers.I am sorry for making that assumption.

Comment: @DanielFischer:Sir sorry for misspelling your name.Sir the formula is not giving the right results.

Comment: @thedarkknight No problem with the misspelling, just pulling your leg a bit ;) I get the correct results from the formula, assuming `a[1] = 1; a[2] = 4`. If the indexing here starts at 0, you have to adjust the indices accordingly; if your indexing of the Fibonacci sequence is such that 0 is not `Fib(0)`, then you also need to adjust the indices. Otherwise, give more information about what values are wrong (index, expected, calculated per formula).